# STM32 rising and falling button interrupt detection

Tags: events, stm32, interruptions

I have button interruption:

```
    void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void)
    {
        if (EXTI_GetITStatus(EXTI_Line0) != RESET){

            if (/* BUTTON IS RELEASED */) {
                /* do something */          
            }
            if (/* BUTTON IS PRESSED */) {
                /* do something else */
            }
        EXTI_ClearITPendingBit(EXTI_Line0);
        }

    }
```

Is there possibility to check this?

Comment: What do you mean "check this"? Also, you should follow the STM32 GPIO/EXTI examples for help, and fill in your exact code that you are using. If you could, please also specify your platform (processor, eval-board, any ties/connections you have placed/soldered, etc).

Comment: It will not work in 99% of cases ie without hardware debouncing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You must set `EXTI` Trigger method as `EXTI_Trigger_Rising_Falling`. So STM32 enter `ISR` when rising and Fallng edge. In `ISR` you can control GPIO pin.If GPIO Pın is set,it must be Rising Edge,Else it must be Falling edge.

```
void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void)
{
    if (EXTI_GetITStatus(EXTI_Line0) != RESET){

        if (PIN==1) {//Rising so pressed
            /* do something */          
        }
        if (PIN==0) {Falling so released
            /* do something else */
        }
    EXTI_ClearITPendingBit(EXTI_Line0);
    }

}
```

NOTE: Above behaves properly with pull-down connected to the button. With pull up, rising and falling will be inverted.

Comment: it is very unlikely to work. Buttons should not be handled this way. The problem is debouncing

Comment: Seconded. This will not work with a button unless additional debouncing circuitry is implemented. I implemented exactly this handler and tested it, came here looking for an improvement because it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For a manual pressed button detection, your code should work.
For some critical signal detection, the interval between edge and checking may make sense.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Answer (score 1):

1.) EXTI is set as EXTI_Trigger_Rising_Falling.

```
void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin){ //interrupt handler
    if(GPIO_Pin == GPIO_PIN_4){ //check interrupt for specific pin              
        if(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_4)){ //check pin state 
            /* do something */
        }
        
        if(!HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_4)){
            /* do something */
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
    if((GPIOE -> IDR & GPIO_PIN_4)){ //IF STATUS PIN is HIGH
        /* do something */
    }
    if(!(GPIOE -> IDR & GPIO_PIN_4)){ //IF STATUS PIN is LOW
        /* do something */
    }
```